# Basic autofac registration / resolution issue (InstancePerLifetimeScope)

Tags: c#, autofac

Given:

```
public class Foo { };
public class Bar {
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
};

public class FooBar
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }

    public FooBar(Bar bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

And the following code:

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Foo>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<Bar>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<FooBar>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var container = builder.Build();

        FooBar foobar1;
        FooBar foobar2;

        using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            foobar1 = container.Resolve<FooBar>();

        }

        using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            foobar2 = container.Resolve<FooBar>();

        }

        Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(foobar1, foobar2));
        Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(foobar1.Bar, foobar2.Bar));
        Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(foobar1.Bar.Foo, foobar2.Bar.Foo));
```

Since foobar1 and foobar2 were resolved within a different lifetimescope and registered as InstancePerLifetimeScope,  I expect:

```
false
false
false
```

However i am getting:

```
true
true
true
```

I'm obviously missing something pretty basic here - what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `container` within lifetime scope, so you are not using them at all. To resolve component use `lifetimeScope`:

```
using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    foobar1 = lifetimeScope.Resolve<FooBar>();
}

using (var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    foobar2 = lifetimeScope.Resolve<FooBar>();
}
```

Comment: Yep, duh ;) thanks.   Knew it had to be something obvious like that.